# Сервисы с переводом терминов и фраз программистов с английского на русский язык

Tags: терминология

Кто-нибудь может подсказать хорошие сервисы с переводом терминов, словосочетаний и фраз программистов, разработчиков, IT-специалистов с английского на русский язык. Либо какие-то специализированные словари, либо словарь каких-то словосочетаний. Это всё, для того, чтобы было проще читать английские книжки по разработке, программированию тем, кто не очень хорошо владеет языком. 
Если кто-то подскажет хорошие учебники по этому направлению буду очень благодарен. Извиняюсь немного за нетематичиский вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению адекватных автоматических переводчиков компьютерной тематики я даже не встречал, хотя искал.

Самый лучший вариант - читать документацию в браузере, и перекидывать непонятные слова или словосочетания в строку поиска в новом окне - найдется либо статья на вики, либо форумное обсуждение.

Comment: ну вот я так и делаю в принципе, но хотелось бы что-нить получше и поэффективнее